# Sort worksheets according from a table array

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have an array that has all of the employee names listed. Each worksheet is named based on the employee name. I was wondering if it was possible to sort the worksheets in the order of the table array.

This is what I have so far:

```
        Dim EmployeeNameRow As Long

        
        Dim EmployeeLastRow As Long
        EmployeeLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim First_Name_Column As Integer
        Dim Last_Name_Column As Integer
        
        First_Name_Column = 1
        Last_Name_Column = 2
        Dim FirstAndLastName As String
        
        'Create the array for which we'll need to add to once we've retrieve all the names
        Dim EmployeeNameArray As Collection
        Set EmployeeNameArray = New Collection

        
        For EmployeeNameRow = 2 To EmployeeLastRow
            FirstAndLastName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(EmployeeNameRow, First_Name_Column).Value & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(EmployeeNameRow, Last_Name_Column).Value
            
            'Add these values to array
            EmployeeNameArray.Add FirstAndLastName

        Next EmployeeNameRow
        
        'Delete any duplicates added to the array
        
        Dim DeletedDuplicatesEmployeeNameArray
        DeletedDuplicatesEmployeeNameArray = RemoveDupes(EmployeeNameArray)
        
        Dim r As Range
        For Each r In DeletedDuplicatesEmployeeNameArray
            Sheets(r.Value).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Next
```

Comment: Are you sorting the worksheet tabs (not the worksheets themselves)? you don't need the array for that, you could sort them without first putting their names into an array

Comment: What problem do you run into when you use your method?

Comment: Isn't `table array` alphabetically sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not answer my clarification question, so I will show you two ways of sorting sheets.

1. Alphabetically sorting the existing sheets. But the sheet "Summary" must be excluded, from sorting and the code places it as last:

```
Sub sortSheetsNames()
   Dim arrSh, sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, i As Long
   
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' ThisWorkbook
   
    'if not "Summary" sheet is the last one, place it as last:
    If Not wb.Worksheets("Summary") Is wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.count) Then
        wb.Worksheets("Summary").Move After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.count)
    End If
    
   ReDim arrSh(1 To wb.Worksheets.count - 1)
   For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        i = i + 1: If i = wb.Worksheets.count Then Exit For
        arrSh(i) = sh.name
   Next
   
   BubbleSort arrSh
   Debug.Print Join(arrSh, "|"): 'just to visually see the sorted array...
   
   For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.count - 1
        If wb.Worksheets(i).name <> arrSh(i) Then
            wb.Worksheets(arrSh(i)).Move Before:=wb.Worksheets(i)
        End If
   Next i
End Sub

Private Sub BubbleSort(arr) 'ascending
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(i): arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

2. Sorting according to the unique concatenated values between columns A and B of the sheet "Summary":

```
Sub SortShetsByArray()
   Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, wS As Worksheet, i As Long, dict As Object
   Dim arr, arrSh, lastR As Long
   
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' ThisWorkbook
   Set wS = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
   
   lastR = wS.Range("A" & wS.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = wS.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2
   Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")

   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i, 1) & " " & arr(i, 2)) = vbNullString 'place the Unique concatenation first/last name in dictionary
   Next i
   
   arrSh = dict.keys
   
    'if not "Summary" sheet is the last one, place it as last:
    If Not wS Is wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.count) Then
        wS.Move After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.count)
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.count - 1
        If wb.Worksheets(i).name <> arrSh(i - 1) Then
            wb.Worksheets(arrSh(i - 1)).Move Before:=wb.Worksheets(i)
        End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

No error handling in case of not a match between the existing sheets name and the one from the array, but this should be easy to insert, I think...

The above codes works on `ActiveWorkbook`, which can be easily replaced with `ThisWorkbook` after testing.

Comment: @RawrRawr7 Please, download a testing workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/9b1oky), test the codes on it and change `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` after seeing working as you need. It can be downloaded in the next 30 days, only...

Answer (score 0):

No need to read the names into an array, etc., just sort the worksheets collection (it is already a collection:

```
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = 1 To .Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To .Count
            If .Item(i).Name <> "Summary" And .Item(j).Name <> "Summary" Then
                If UCase(.Item(i).Name) > UCase(.Item(j).Name) Then ' Check if the current position is wrong
                   .Item(j).Move Before:=.Item(i) 'bring it over
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    End With
```